# Chemical equilibrium and Le Chatelier's principle

Tags: equilibrium

$$\ce{energy + 2KClO3 (s) <=> 2KCl(s) + 3O2 (g)}$$

The reaction will be more active in the reverse direction if:

1. $\ce{O_2}$ is added
2. more $\ce{KCl}$ salt is added.
3. More $\ce{KClO3}$ is added
4. Increasing the temperature.

My thoughts:

I think (1) and (2) are both right. But the book states that only (1) works and I can't find reason for that searching google was useless.

$K_c = [\ce{O2}]^3$, so if we increased $\ce{KCl}$ or decreased $\ce{KClO3}$ it won't affect the equilibrium?

---

$$\ce{Fe(OH)(s) <=> Fe^{2+}  + 2OH^-}$$ The reaction will be more active in the reverse direction if : ... is added

1. $\ce{KOH}$
2. $\ce{Na_2S}   $
3. $\ce{Fe(OH)_2}  $
4. $\ce{Fe(NO3)2}$

Won't it be (1) and (4)? The book says it's (4) only.

Comment: Why do you think (1) and (2) are correct?

Comment: Can you write out the formula for the equilibrium constant?

Comment: Because if I added KCL le chattele ( never written his name right)  says the reaction will go in the direction which makes it get back to equilibrium and so will happen if we added o2.  maybe it's misunderstanding from me.

Comment: Ok ,    Kc = [0_2]^3

Comment: You're on the right track there, please consider adding your thoughts presented in your comments into your question.

Comment: Now I think I understand. When I add o2 I will increase the number of moles  and as a result the concentration will increase but the KCl is out of the Kc so it won't affect the equilibrium , right ? The problem is that my teacher told me that is wrong ...

Comment: I think your reasoning is sound,  (have upvoted as well)

Comment: Why do you think  KCl is out of the Kc? You're wrong...

Comment: Because it's solid (long explanation). H2O liquid is not counted too

Comment: @Mithoron perhaps expand on that into an answer?

Comment: Help , now he confused me more.

Comment: Bro, I think I am right check this : http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/equilibria/kc.html       (Writing an expression for Kc for a heterogeneous equilibrium)  You will see "The important difference this time is that you don't include any term for a solid in the equilibrium expression." this too http://bouman.chem.georgetown.edu/S02/lect8/lect8.htm

Comment: You are correct @HoytVolker - and the answer below provides a good explanation emphasising what you found.

Comment: But I don't understand what he does mean by oxygen pressure I think we are not playing with pressure , are we ?

Comment: @mamun's comment below explains what is happening

Comment: @HoytVolker I would suggest taking the 2nd question you edited in and writing that as a separate question, linked to this one.

Comment: Ok , thanks for the suggestion , I will. Ops , seems that I can't I have reached the limited 2 questions.

Answer (score 1):

1) Increasing Oxygen pressure will increase the reverse rate because to reestablish equilibrium some of the oxygen should be consumed.
2) Out of system due to precipitation.
3) Out of system due to precipitation.
4) This is endothermic reaction. So increasing temperature will increase the forward rate to consume the added heat.

Comment: "Oxygen pressure" ??

Comment: Adding gas phase oxygen means increasing the partial pressure of oxygen.

Comment: Because we are increasing the number of atoms in Unit of volume ?  p(ro) = m/Vol

Comment: Yeah. Think about it from mathematical point of view: You have a constant K which has numerical value of 100. K is also equal to ${O_2^3}$. So that means ${O_2}$ is 4.64 bar roughly. Now you increase it to 5 bar and the equilibrium wants it to stay at 4.64 bar. So the equilibrium will consume 0.35 bar worth of oxygen molecule to reestablish it to 100.

Comment: A reference that helps explain what is happening with the oxygen is at http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Equilibria/Chemical_Equilibria/The_Equilibrium_Constant/Effect_of_Pressure_on_Gas-Phase_Equilibria

Comment: Thanks I am checking it atm @santiago. Thanks too mamun maths explanation is better , but please check the new example it confused me.